# How to change x-axes interval on Chart.js 3.3.2?

Tags: chart.js, intervals, xticks

I am making exchange rate chart with 3.3.2 version of Chart.js
I want to make Xticks values to this [3 months ago, 1 month ago, 1 week ago, 1 day ago] with same interval.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooANF.png)

```js
var ctx = 'myChart';
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["3M", "","","",    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
            "", "", "1M","",    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1W","",    "", "", "1D",""],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Exchange Rate',
            data: [1308.8,1308.3,1300.5,1306.1,1294.9,1291.1,1277.5,1275.9,1280.1,1273.5,1280.7,1282.2, 1291.5, 1291.4, 1302.2, 1303.8, 1303.1, 1304.3, 1312.8, 1319.4, 1310,
            1301.7,1300.8,1303.8,1307.3,1303.8, 1295,1291.4 ,1276.2 ,1265.8 ,1266.1 ,1261.6 ,1265.4 ,1265.8 ,1281.7 ,1283.8,1280.7, 1278.7, 1273.4, 1280,1273.8,1280.7, 1293,1298.8 ,1303.9 ,1304.1,
            1312.6, 1318.3, 1317.3, 1321.1, 1331.3, 1338.3, 1341.6, 1336.9, 1341.5, 1338.7, 1338,1324,  1326.6, 1322.5, 1322,1321.4 ,1322.3 ,1319.2],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor:  '#f26c6d',
            pointBorderColor:'transparent',
            pointBorderWidth:4,
            borderWidth: 2,
            tension: 0.5
        }]
    },
    options: {
        //responsive : false,
         scales: {
            x: { grid: { display: false }}
        ,   y: { grid: { display: false }}
        }
        ,plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Dollar",
                padding: {
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 30
                }
            }
            ,legend: {
                position:'bottom'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:80vh; width: 100%">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-VCHVc5miKoln972iJPvkQrUYYq7XpxXzvqNfiul1H4aZDwGBGC0lq373KNleaB2LpnC2a/iNfE5zoRYmB4TRDQ==" crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

How can I make the interval on the x-axis the same even if the number of data between each xticks is different?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking, what interval to be the same (the same as what?). Do you want the last day (the interval from "1D" to the right end of the axis) to have the same size on x axis as the interval between "1M" and "1D" and the same as the interval from "3M" to "1M"? BTW, to show all the labels  in your code above, you'll have to set `ticks: {autoSkip: false}` in the `x` scale properties.

Comment: Yes, I want to have the same size on x axis as the interval between "1M" and "1D" and the same as the interval from "3M" to "1M" even if the number of data between "1M" and "1D" &  "3M" and "1M" is different.